# Сохранение изображения Google Static Maps API

Tags: php, google-maps-api

Как сохранить такое изображение себе на сервер?

Само изображение:

```
$str = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x300&&zoom=13&&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7CМуром, Московская 105
&key=AIzaSyDLzWXCDzG8Ui_APDFhNmq9YRJMbUbBj3Y';
```

Пробовал так:

```
copy ( $str, 's.png' );
```

и вот такой функцией:

```
function SaveImage($url) {
    $dir = 'img/';
    $Image = @file_get_contents($url);
    if(!$Image) {
        return "Не удалось получить данные файла по ссылке";
    }
     else {
        $ExplodeUrl = explode("/", $url);
        $FileName = $ExplodeUrl[count($ExplodeUrl)-1];
        if(file_exists($dir.$FileName)) {
            $FileName = rand(10000000, 99999999).$FileName;
        }
        $CreateNewFile = fopen($dir.$FileName, "w+");
        $WriteInFile = fwrite($CreateNewFile, $Image);
        return $FileName;
     }
}
echo Saveimage($str);
```

Тестил на картинках с расширением .png или .jpg, то с других серверов все сохраняет нормально

Answer (score 0, accepted):

очень странно, но сохраняет, если адреса писать координатамии всё сохраняет

```
$str = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?cneter=Murom&size=400x300&zoom=13&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C55.57722084215371,42.051084181510646&key=AIzaSyDLzWXCDzG8Ui_APDFhNmq9YRJMbUbBj3Y';
$local='tmp.png';
file_put_contents($local, file_get_contents($str));
```